# What is multicast scheduling?

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols

I am currently working on a project with Stanford's netFPGA cards and want to implement a simple example of a primitive multicast scheduler just to demonstrate the concept.
Any examples or documentation of multicast scheduling would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help :

http://www.visualland.net/view.php?cid=891&lang=en